# Using Conan and CocoaPods together / Merging two xcconfig files

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, conan

I have a C++ library that I've written using [Conan]https://conan.io to manage library dependencies. I'd like to use that library in a React Native app. In order to use the Native Modules Bridge, you need to use [CocoaPods]https://cocoapods.org. Both CocoaPods and Conan want to set an xcconfig in XCode to configure search paths. Is there any way to merge the two, or to use both tools in combination? Right now I'm hand merging the files, which works but is obviously not ideal.

I'd rather not switch everything over to CocoaPods, as this library will be used on platforms other than iOS/Cocoa. Also, the libraries I depend on are all autotools based and are a lot easier to deal with in Conan. Alternatively, is there an easy way to wrap a Conan package in CocoaPods?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look to the new Xcode toolchain in https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/apple.html, it aggregates different .xcconfig files in a ``conan_config.xcconfig`` one for usage. Probably use the same pattern?

Comment: Thanks @drodri, as below I ended up going the other way around: making a CocoaPod for the Conan project and using that to wrap up all of the libraries needed. Seems to work, and has the advantage of making a universal library at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by making a local CocoaPod podspec that just wraps up the Conan project and produces a CocoaPod for it. This worked well in my case, since I only need the one Conan dependency. I suppose I could have also produced a Conan project that just outputs all of the headers and libraries needed, which would probably work well if I needed more libraries. I did add an option to my Conan package to copy ("import") all of the dependent libraries into the build folder so I don't have to make separate pods for them too. Here's roughly what my podspec looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name = "Project"
    spec.summary = "..."
    spec.homepage = 'https://github.com/...'
    spec.authors = "..."
    spec.license = { :type => 'LGPL' }
    spec.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/...' }

    spec.version = "0.0.1"
  
    spec.platform = :ios
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
  
    spec.prepare_command = <<-CMD
    conan install . -if build_ios-sim -pr:b=default -pr:h=ios-sim -b=missing -o copy_libs=True
    conan build . -bf build_ios-sim
    conan install . -if build_ios -pr:b=default -pr:h=ios -b=missing -o copy_libs=True
    conan build . -bf build_ios
    mkdir lib
    for i in build_ios-sim/lib/*.a; do
      f=`basename "$i"`
      ls {build_ios,build_ios-sim}/lib/"$f"
      lipo -create -output "lib/$f" {build_ios,build_ios-sim}/lib/"$f"
    done
    mkdir include
    cp src/libname.h include/
  CMD
  
    spec.source_files = "include/*.h"
    spec.ios.vendored_libraries = "lib/*.a"
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
    spec.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  end
```

One advantage of this technique over integrating Conan directly into XCode is that you can produce universal libraries. I think I've used lipo correctly to do that, though I haven't actually deployed to an iOS device yet to test it.